# toggle checkbox using react failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm picking up react. But often time I have no clue what's the error. Below code did not render properly, and in the console of jsbin it shows no error.

```
const App = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {checked: false}
  },
  handleCheck() {
     this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
  },
  render() {
      return(
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} />
    <p>This box is {this.state.checked}</p>
    </div>
    )


  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

https://jsbin.com/dehafizaba/1/edit
Need advise.

Comment: Your jsbin contains different code than your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "works fine". The problem is that React doesn't show a string representation of the boolean value. If you output something else it works, e.g.:

```
<p>This box is {this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}</p>
```

Comment: I expect true and false from `{this.state.checked}` like in angular, but react will not show anything?

Comment: I think the expression has to return something renderable, i.e. an element, string or number. A boolean value is arguable not something that is usually rendered. You can explicitly convert the value to a string: `{String(this.state.checked)}`.

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean`'s won't get printed in React. Use `toString()` to convert them into `string`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/557ab8wa/1/